# Fetch element using ImportHTML with XPath in Google Sheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I'm trying to use the [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) `IMPORTHTML()` function to get the text inside of a `<span>` from a website.

What `xpath` argument do I need, in order to produce the output: **`Score 50`**?

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="left">
        <div id="search" class="input">
            <span class="select-box">Test Section</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtSymbol" class="select-box">
            <input type="button" id="btnHistory" class="input-button">
        </div>
        <span id="score" class="score">Score 50 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are some of the `xpath` values I've already tried using, but none of them have worked:

1. `//span[@class='score']/@content` I get `#N/A`
2. `//div[@class='search']/span[@class='score']/@content` I get `#N/A`
3. `//div[@class='search']/span[1]/@content` I get `#N/A`

Comment: Element text is accessed with `text()` function instead of `@content` attribute that does not exists. Try this one `//div[@class='search']/following-sibling::span[@id='score']/text()`

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69482381/fetch-element-using-importhtml-with-xpath-in-google-sheet#comment122811866_69482381), to get the node's text you should use **`text()`** instead of `@content`.

So this should work:

```text
//span[@class='score']/text()
```